# how to design a RESTful api for redeem a coupon?

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url

I am designing a RESTful api for coupon redemption.
Each coupon can be redeemed only once, after redemption the coupon is on longer valid.

`(POST) /coupons/{couponCode}/redeem`

seems violate the RESTful guidelines since `redeem` is a verb.
can I just change `redeem` to `redemption`?
or can I just use

`(POST) /coupons/{couponCode}`?

btw I am not quite sure why use POST instead of PATCH, is it because of PATCH is idempotent and POST is not? I mean, when the coupon is redeemed for the first time, it will be marked as `redeemed` in database, but once it's done, the same request won't update this value anymore.

Answer (score 3):

> seems violate the RESTful guidelines since redeem is a verb

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers.

So all of these choices are *fine*

```
POST /coupons/{couponCode}/redeem
POST /coupons/{couponCode}
POST /{couponCode}/redeem
POST /i/am/a/banana
POST /4ccd2f6f-a81e-4b70-b45c-20ce9f8732b5
```

Identifier spelling conventions are like variable naming conventions; they exist only to ease the burden of people, and are subject to local convention.  The machines don't care.

The thing that matters is that the target uri used for your change matches the identifier of the resource in the cache that you want to [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

> I am not quite sure why use POST instead of PATCH, is it because of PATCH is idempotent and POST is not?

No.  The difference is that PATCH promises that the payload is a patch document, which is to say a representation of a set of edits to the representation of "the" resource, whereas POST just says "this is a message to be processed by the resource".

(Both POST and PATCH are not idempotent, as it happens.)

Imagine a document store, where the documents are about one terabyte in size.  You might want to change one of those documents.  The natural way to do it is to `GET` the current representation, make your changes, and then `PUT` your version of the document back.  But if your change is very small, then there's a lot of wasted work carrying duplicated copies of the document around.

So instead, we use PATCH, so that we can instead copy a small representation of the edit, rather than the full document.

POST is more general -- it's an unsafe message with a body, and that's pretty much all it promises.  That body *might* be a new representation of the resource, or a patch to be applied to the current representation, or something entirely different.

> why use redeem doesn't violate REST? shouldn't be verbs only HTTP methods?

Because [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is an architectural style, and it says that resource identifiers should be URL ([RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)) -- although these days that is generally understood to mean URI ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) -- or URN ([RFC 8141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141)).

If you look at RFC 3986, I think you will find that the word "verb" doesn't appear anywhere in the document.  You can review the ABNF rules for interpreting URI, and there is nothing about verbs in there anywhere.

REST doesn't care -- the URI is, in its primary use case, just an opaque sequence of bytes that are used by the client.

For example, try clicking on this link in your browser, does it work?

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stop

The fact that "stop" happens to be a verb in English doesn't interfere with its function.

> I also see some RESTful design guidelines suggest not to use verbs

Yup, the web is full of advice from people who don't understand the subject, or who do understand the subject and don't articulate it clearly, and so on.

REST doesn't offer enforce any particular URI design style.

In REST, the identifier is just an identifier, like a UUID, a hash signature, or a surrogate key.  Within the context of an HTTP message, it doesn't *mean* anything, it's just a cache key.  The message semantics come from the [method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1), not the request-target.

```
GET /A/post HTTP/1.1

POST /B/get HTTP/1.1

DELETE /C/put HTTP/1.1

PUT /D/patch HTTP/1.1
```

There's no ambiguity in these request lines, the first token is the method that defines the semantics, the second token is just an arbitrary identifier.  The machines will get them right every single time.

## Recommended Viewing

- [Jim Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)
- [Stefan Tilkov, 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM)

Comment: why use `redeem` doesn't violate REST? shouldn't be verbs only HTTP methods? I also see some RESTful design guidelines suggest not to use verbs, e.g. https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#138

Comment: REST is opinionated on uniform interfaces. HTTP verbs provide that uniformity. Moving verbs into the URL breaks that uniformity. I suppose one could create a URL convention and ignore the HTTP verbs but it would need to be widely accepted to be useful

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to use a url route where you expose the redeem action. This route should use the POST http request because you will modify a resource on the server, and will take as parameter your couponCode.

```
(POST) /coupons/redeem/{couponCode}
```

I don't think there is a difference between redeem and redemption. I think a verb like redeem is better to designate an action.

http PATCH or PUT request can be used too. As a convention, we use PATCH or PUT to update a resource after it has been created to change one of its attributes. If you are willing to use PATCH request to update let's say a coupon that you already created, then you can define a url route without the redeem action. The request body would contain the fields to be updated for the coupon object (for example status from "pending" to "redeemed")

```
(PATCH / PUT) /coupons/{couponCode}
```

Many use the following convention:

```
GET /objects (return list of objects)
GET /objects/id (return object)
PUT /objects/id (update object)
POST /objects (add object)
DELETE /objects/id (remove object)
```